# Can we assign a keyboard key to tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a piano in python tkinter. So, I have created buttons representing the keys and whenever we click it we get a sound.Now, its really difficult to click it at sequence. So, I have thought to assign a keyboard key to the button.So, the button gets clicked.

Thank you in advance.
(Note: I have already assigned a command in button to play the sound)

Comment: You can bind `<Key>` event to root window. Then check which key is pressed in the callback and call the required function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pynput` package.

```
pip install pynput
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `btn.bind()` function. Use the `"<Key>"` string with the keyboard button you have in mind then pass the function as a second argument. Be careful to add an argument to your function so that it recieves the event. Check this link:
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm
Also this video:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GLnNPjL1U2g